# kind - exposing service to host

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I would like to run an application in local cluster for development purposes with `kind` using `docker`. Based on the description `https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/` I defined the cluster

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
- role: worker
  extraPortMappings:
    - containerPort: 30000
      hostPort: 5432
      protocol: TCP
```

and the deployment with container:

```
        containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
```

and the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  database
spec:
selector:
  name:  app
type:  NodePort
ports:
- name:  postgres
  port:  5432
  targetPort:  5432
  nodePort: 30000
```

which I assumed should allow me to connect with dbeaver from my windows 11 host. This looks to be not working so I would like to ask, how should I configure that to being able to access it from host. What I have already tried is: `localhost:30000, 127.0.0.1:30000` and also `127.0.0.1:5432, localhost:5432`

Also `kubectl get services` command tells me that:

`Type: NodePort, Port(S): 5432:30000/TCP, External-IP: <none>, Cluster-Ip:10.96.211.69, name:something`

Comment: One obvious place to double-check: if you `kubectl describe service database`, under `Endpoints:`, does it say `<none>` or something else?  ("Something else" is good, `<none>` implies the Service's selector doesn't match the Pods' labels but could cause this problem.)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, I turned out to be that I placed `extractPortMappings` inside `worker` node instead of `control-plane`. It's weird that it doesn't fail but after moving this part to correct place it started to work!

So the solution is to change to this:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30000
    hostPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
- role: worker
```